# How to vertically align all HGroups in application to "middle"?

Tags: css, flex4, skinning

In my application all HGroups should be vertically aligned to `middle`. As this is a property of `HorizontalLayout` which is exposed via HGroup's `verticalAlign` *property* (not style) I can't set it in CSS. Also, while Groups are not skinnable I can't assign a custom skin.

Is creating a subclass like `VerticallyAlignedHGroup` my only option or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run across this as well and after some research wound up doing as you mentioned and created my own subclass of HGroup that had verticalAlign set to "middle".  Wish I had a better solution for you, but I've been unable to find one.

Answer (score -1):

Borek,

Normally you can only apply vertical alignment using the CSS property `verical-align` to table elements (th, td).  However...

If you're using DIVs then just fake it using `table-cell` display. You will have to wrap up your `.verticallyAlignedHGroup` in a parent DIV so you can declare its display as table though.

```
#verticalWrapper { display: table; }
.verticalAlignHGroup { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

The HTML would look something like this

```
<div id="verticalWrapper"> <!-- display: table -->
  <div class="verticalAlignHGroup"> <!-- display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle -->
    Some content
  </div>
  <div class="verticalAlignHGroup"> <!-- display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle -->
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This question was about a problem in Adobe Flex.